# magento adding a product

Tags: magento

Hai

In my magneto project, When I add a product some times it shows part number fields, some times it not shown, What is this?? I want to give part number in my entire product, what can I do to show the part number permanently

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way that can happen is if you have created different attribute sets, and you aren't assigning every product the same attribute set.

You may have created a new set that has the part number field, and sometimes when you create a new product, you select the new attribute set, and other times perhaps you are leaving it on the default attribute set which doesn't have the part number field.

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry dont forgent to see the reffernce:

http://targetphp.coolpage.biz/index.php/more-about-magento/50-how-to-add-new-product-in-magento-.html